# filter on comma separated string within list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List which contains a comma separated string value which holds tags.

I want to filter the List based on a value in this comma separated string.

The comma separated string in the List will typically look like the following:

```
list.Tags = "Tag 1, Tag2, Another Tag"
```

I have tried the following but receive object reference not set to an instance errors. The NextDate is just a clause to return the appropriate items in the list, and now need to find 'tags' that match. I would only search for 1 tag.

```
list = list.Where(x => x.NextDate >= todaysDate).Where(x => x.Tags.Contains("Tag 1")).ToList();
```

Any ideas how I can filter my list for a certain Tag?

[The Duplicate question does not answer my question, I'm trying to get the correct syntax for filtering my list and that question does not help. My question is related to Linq syntax]

Comment: Will this Linq execute in memory or against a database? If you're working in memory, you can simply use list.Tags.Split(',')

Comment: Your approach doesn't work if the tag is "Tag 10", so split it as Moeri has mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a null check:

```
list = 
  list.Where(
    x => null != x.NextDate && 
    x.NextDate >= todaysDate && 
    null != x.Tags && 
    x.Tags.Contains("Tag 1"))
  .ToList();
```

If you want to make sure you matching the exact tag (ie you have Tag 1 and Tag 11):

```
list = 
  list.Where(
    x => null != x.NextDate && 
    x.NextDate >= todaysDate && 
    null != x.Tags && 
    x.Tags.Split.Contains("Tag 1"))
  .ToList();
```

Comment: ppittle, the second code block is missing method brackets on the Split(). It also doesn't seem to work properly? It doesn't seem to return some items that I would expect to return. The first code block does work but as you mentioned doesn't return an exact match.

Comment: Need to add the separator to the Split method, so it should be .Split(','). That fixes it.

Comment: No need for the `null != x.NextDate` part. If `NextDate` is a non-nullable struct, that never happens. In other cases, the `>=` operator should take care of cases where the left operand is `null`, so no need to worry about it.